# Non Characteristic boundary condition of a PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm a bit confused with the calculation for checking the non characteristic boundary conditions.
So in my book (PDE by Lawrence C Evans), it says for a PDE $$F(Du,u,x)$$
consider the flat boundary that lies on the plane $x_n=0$. Then we can consider the initial conditions are admissible as long as it satisfies, $F_{p_n}(p^0,z^0,x^0)\neq0$. My question is how should be understand this $F_{p_n}$.

Say for example we have the following situation:

> Let $V:= \{(x_1, x_2) ~\vert~ x_1>x_2 \} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, and $\partial V$ be the diagonal $\partial V:=\{(x_1,x_2)~\vert~ x_1=x_2 \}$. Consider the Cauchy problem
>
> $$\left\{
> \begin{alignedat}{2}
> u u_{x_1} + u_{x_2} &= 0\quad && \text{in}~V\\
> u(x_1,x_1)&=\frac{1}{2}x_1 \quad &&\text{on}~\partial V
> \end{alignedat}\right.$$

What should be the corresponding plane and hence the $F_{p_n}$ value.
Appreciate your help

Comment: In the context of first order PDEs, $p_{n}$ usually refers to the derivative of your function $u$ with respect to $x_{n}$ i.e $p_{n} = u_{x_{n}}$. Hence, $F_{p_{n}} = F_{u_{x_{n}}}$ i.e treat $u_{x_{n}}$ _as its own coordinate_ for each $n$ and take the partial derivative of $F$ with respect to that coordinate. Hence, in your problem $$F = uu_{x_{1}} + u_{x_{2}} = up_{1} + p_{2} = 0$$ and so $F_{p_{1}} = u, F_{p_{2}} = 1$.

Comment: Thank you @mattos for the comment. So does this means, $F_{p_n}=(F_{p_1},F_{p_2})=(\frac{1}{2}x_1,1)\neq0$ will give the suitable boundary conditions right?

Comment: Which means none of the points are suitable?